# Bugzilla stopped working after upgrade to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, bugzilla

I have had a working version of bugzilla on 10.04.

After I upgraded to 11.10 (_>11.04 -> 11.10) now BZ is not working.

While trying

```
./checksetup.pl
```

I get a gdlib error.

Trying to solve it with:

```
./install_module --all
```

throws this error:

```
**UNRECOVERABLE ERROR** Could not find gdlib-config in the search path. Please install libgd 2.0.28 or higher. If you want to try to
compile anyway, please rerun this script with the option
--ignore_missing_gd.
```

- Trying to use the --ignore_missing_gd as suggested gives the same error.

Neither

```
apt-get install libgd2-xpm
apt-get install libgd2-noxpm
```

solve it.

Will appreciate assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
I couldn't make it work. I had to backup my DB, and reinstall V4.0.2.

Mainly folloewed a great step by step [guide here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/install-bugzilla-on-linux/)

Downloaded the Version from [Bugzilla site](http://www.bugzilla.org/download/)

Also, had to add the following in apache2.conf

```
<Directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/somedir>
    Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

And

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
```

All is working now.